# Asterisk and automatic hangup

Tags: proxy, asterisk, rtp

I am having some problems with asterisk IP PBX ( FreePBX).

I am having two clients and I want that all of the SIP and RTP traffic should go through proxy. SIP and RTP Traffic is going through the proxy machine currently but I changed the proxy implementation such that instead of routing the media or RTP traffic through asterisk , proxy automatically forwards it to the other client.
If A and B represents client, P represents proxy  so in case of SIP traffic the flow is

A  <--> P <--> PBX <--> P <--> B

while in the case of RTP traffic the flow is

A  <-->  P <--> B

but now the problem that occurs is the Asterisk automatically issues a hangup request ( bye message) after some time.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Asterisk server is dropping the call on rtp timeout. Please change rtptimeout to 30000 in your sip.conf file.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+sip+rtptimeout